# Passing local environment variables via SSH not working

Tags: server, ssh, environment-variables

Running Ubuntu 22 on both local and remote.

I'm trying to pass some environment variables from my local to the remote during ssh; the end goal is being able to define GIT_AUTHOR_NAME as per http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/carry-git-settings.htm.

But, the env variables are not getting set on the remote after SSH. This includes the `LANG` variable which should be preset to pass through from my understanding.

**Local:**

I have added `GIT_*` to `SendEnv` (tried placing it at the top, globally and also within Host, in case it helped!). `LANG` already exists:

~/.ssh/config

```
SendEnv LANG LC_* GIT_*

Host 1.2.3.4
  HostName 1.2.3.4
  User username
  SendEnv LANG LC_* GIT_*
```

and the env variables are set:

`echo $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`
returns
`ABC`

`echo $LANG` returns `en_NZ.UTF-8`

**Remote:**

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
...
UsePAM yes
...
PermitUserEnvironment yes
...
AcceptEnv LANG LC_* GIT_*
...
```

and have reloaded remote ssh  `/etc/init.d/ssh reload`

**SSH:**

`ssh user@server -v`

```
...
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_NZ.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env GIT_AUTHOR_NAME = ABC
Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1013-aws x86_64)
...
```

It seems to be correctly sending the env variable, with no obvious errors in the log, but on the remote...

`echo $LANG` returns `C.UTF-8` (which I presume is the default)

`echo $GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` returns blank

So, my environment variables are **not** being passed over ssh.

I've read a few other posts about `LANG` being overwritten in .profile, but that doesn't explain why my custom `GIT_*` variables aren't working.

I have also tried:

`ssh user@server -o SendEnv=LANG`
and
`ssh user@server -o SendEnv=GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`

and it's exactly the same problem.

I'm thinking there must be other settings on the remote (in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ??) I need to review, but unsure.

Any help, most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` actually an *environment variable* or just a shell variable? What does `declare -p GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` return in the local (bash) shell?

Comment: @steeldriver `declare -p GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` returns `declare -x GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="ABC"` in local shell